# What movie formats can I play on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

What formats can my Xbox 360 play? When I try to play a movie off my USB on the xbox, often it works and sometimes it just comes up with a error saying that Xbox can't read this format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Microsoft's support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/audio-video-setup-and-use/audio-video-playback), you can use the following codecs when streaming from  USB: WMV(Unprotected), Mpeg4, H.264, AVI.

Further investigation of that same page reveals that that means you can use the following file formats: avi, .divx, .mp4, .m4v, mp4v, .mov, .wmv

Also, when playing something from USB, the file can be no larger than 4 GB. It also cannot play DivX files older than DivX 5.0.

Comment: God you ninja'd me!

Comment: Weirdly for me I can play mkv files as long as they are on a shared folder, only one mkv in the folder on my PC fine, they cannot be read off a USB key or the HDD on the 360. It makes, NO SENSE at all to me. I can play anything under 1080p from USB in the formats given above.

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb is that it will almost ALWAYS play a wmv file, but I've had some luck with avi files that have MP3 audio, some mp4 files and even more files listed after [the jump to Support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/watch-dvds-movies)

Answer (score 0):

From a guide on [how to play MKV on Xbox](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/how-to-play-mkv-on-xbox360.html), i know:

*Xbox 360 has strict requirement for the input formats and only WMV, AVI, H.264 and MPEG-4 are compatible with Xbox 360.*

This guide also introduces more tips about Xbox 360.