# XBOX 360 won't see video files in /Content folder of USB drive

Tags: xbox-360

I used my XBOX 360 to format a USB drive.

When I mounted the drive on a Linux box, I saw an empty /Content folder and a "name.txt" (which appears to be the drive name in 2-byte-wide characters).

I then copied a few MP4 files to the /Content folder, reconnected the drive to my XBOX 360, and went to System Video Player.

System Video Player says there are no videos on my drive.

How do I get System Video Player to see the files I've put in /Content? Do I need to create a subdirectory or something?

As a test, I used the XBOX 360 to copy several games to the USB drive, and that seemed to work, so I don't think it's a drive issue.

When I mounted the drive on my Linux box again (after copying games/etc), it showed some "randomly" named directories, but still nothing in Content.

I'm guessing that's DRM related.

Can I get the XBOX 360 to play non-DRM video on my USB drive?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/what-movie-formats-can-i-play

Comment: I'm pretty sure the /Content folder is for xbox config files (placed there when formatting the drive on the xbox). What I've done to get my USB's to work is format them on a PC (or in your case Linux), and format the USB to Fat32. You can then throw your video files directly onto the USB and your xbox will be able to read them.

Comment: @onewho Thanks! Just to be clear, you're saying that the XBOX "format" command does NOT create a FAT32 system on the disk and I need to format the drive differently, correct? In other words, XBOX's format isn't sufficient? Dallium: I actually read that question earlier: the problem here is the XBOX 360 won't even *see* the files. Once I get it to do that, then I'll worry about if it can play them :)

Comment: @barrycarter I'm unsure what format xbox uses when it formats a disk, but I've always had issues using an xbox formatted disk on anything that wasn't xbox (meaning I could not put videos onto it). You only need to format a disk on xbox (for xbox) when you're using it for games or saves (or other xbox specific files). Otherwise stick with formatting it on a computer.

Comment: @onewho I formatted my USB external HDD on Xbox along with a couple thumbdrives. I could read them fine on computer. That's how I got to make any image I found on the internet a background for my 360. I think your right about the Content folder being for config files though. On my smaller thumbdrives that were formatted, I didn't see a Content folder but as long as the file was in the correct format (.wmv, .mp4, .avi) it would be visible and play fine.